# How Apple Push Notifications Deliver to the User in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Am developing an iPhone app. In my current iPhone app i want to integrate APNS that we want to send a messages to the user. I gathered information about APNS. But, still i have some doubts on the APNS.

1. How APN works that means how the push notifications showing to the user?
2. If our iPhone app get closed from Background, the Apple push notification will work or our app should be in run?
3. What will happen if we send a notification to the user but,if the user is in offline. The message will deliver to the user once the user gets online (Get network connection) or the message won't show to the user?
4. Push Notifications will be show the user if the user doesn't open the app in their iPhone?

Can anyone please guide me on these doubts? I hope on you friends. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer the question posed in the title, a push notification is sent over cellular using SMS (if I recall correctly). Or, its similar to a SMS - just a different message type (I'd have to read one of the specifications to verify it, and they are painful to read).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not follow [Apple developer library](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) instructions. I have doubts about your understanding of APNS and its working.

When you send the notification to user, and his cell is off or not connected to the internet, he/she will get message/notification when his/her cell will turn on or connect to the network.

And Push Notifications also work when your application is in backGround or user is not using the application.

Hope this information can clear your confusion, you should look in to the [apple developer videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) and SDK about push notifications.
Also [this is SOreadytohelp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381387/push-notification-background-process-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

You asked quite a few questions.  I'll try to answer some of them as well as I know:

1. How APN works: You send a message to Apple's servers with the specific device ID.  Apple will deliver that message to the iOS device.  (You likely want a more specific answer, so please ask.)
2. If your app has been allowed background app notifications, then they will be delivered in the background. (The user can enable/disable this)
3. If the particular iOS device is not connected to the network, notifications will be queued.  But, identical notifications will get discarded and only the most recent will get delivered. See: [Quality of Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW4)
4. Yes (basically the same answer for 2).